# Counting the number of input's and textarea's with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, count

I have a script that only works in jquery 1.7.2.  I'm also getting a lot of conflicts with this script.

Is there an alternative to this approach?  I'm trying to count the number of input's and textarea's that have data typed inside them.  I just need a number.

Here is my current script:

```
$('#form_register').on('keyup', function() {
var number = $('#form_register').find('input, textarea')
// filter out every empty input/textarea
.filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() != '';
}).length;
$('.inputCount').val('There are ' + number + ' empty input fields');
console.log('test');
});​
```

Comment: That should work... Does `#form-register` allow a `keyup` event?

Comment: Hmmm.... Not sure. How could I tell?

Comment: Try using all of your code inside a different event, such as button, and see if it works. ie: `$('button').click(function(){ // your code })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `change` handler too, to prevent someone paste the text inside a field.

**EDIT :**
To count upwards as you asked in your comment:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/oguzaj/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
$('#form_register').on('keyup change', function() {
    var number = 0;
    $(this).find('input, textarea').each(function(){
       if( this.value !== ''){
          $('.input_count').val(number++);
       }
    });       
});
```

To redo to count downwards ([DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oguzaj/2/edit)) just use `===` and exclude the *print* from the `each function`:

```
       if( this.value === ''){
          number++;
       }
       $('.input_count').val(number);
```

If you have more issues, try to wrap the code into:

```
(function($){ // remap '$' to jQuery
 
    // CODE HERE

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The `input` event is pretty nice where its available as well...  Also, no need for `$(this).val()` you can just use `this.value` since none of the inputs are `select`s

Comment: @gnarf thanks for remembering me. To write `$(this)` was in my fingers, ...than I just added `.val()` :D

Comment: Instead of making the number count down, how would you make it count up?  Thank u for your time and help.

Comment: I can't figure out why this does not work:   http://www.41q.org/admin/data/test.php

Comment: @gnarf Always feel free to edit/improve my answers. Now I had to do it :D

Comment: Roko, I finally got it to work.  very grateful... BUT, I don;t understand why the numbering starts at 16, 17, 18, 19, etc...  I does not start at 1.  Instead it starts at "16"